# how to fix redis server timeout from time to time

Tags: python, redis, connection-pooling

i've been having issue with redis since I installed it in production. 
The redis server is installed on a single machine and it has clients connected to it.

Using the default redis conf file. [here](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf)

It times out about 20 times a day [image]
The usage of it is no more then a 1000 times a day.

This is where i'm at with research :

1. thinking it might be a problem with the redis-py not closing
   connections since I found ~1000 opened client connections.
2. It might be the redis configuration .

Did someone encounter this?

Comment: I just have some basic idea about redis. It has  also some distributed locks which it holds on some resources . Is it a possibility that those resources get accessed simultaneously and are locked for a time period and so there is a time-out.

Comment: i am unclear as to what is the correct approach you are suggestion to fix this ? or even to validate this?

Comment: can you check in redis.conf  whether timout value is set . Since you said usage is limited to 1000 times a day which is not much and can be handled easily , I was thinking of other possibilities. Which version of redis are you using? Read this page for client timeouts `http://redis.io/topics/clients` . You can set the client timeout value to something higher `CONFIG SET timeout <value>`

Comment: By default redis has no client timeout. Perhaps your client using redis-py is making new connections instead of reusing them from the pool, causing some max client limit being reached and existing redis-py connections to timeout? https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: i read the docs on the redis-py . it's using a connection pool behind the scences.